# Angular 2 functions library

Tags: function, angular, angular-services, angular-components

In my application I'll need to create a functions library to be accessed from different components. What is the best way to do this? Do I need to make a service with all the functions or a class or a module or a component?

In this library if I call a function from a component and this function need to access a variable in the caller, will it be possible to do?

Comment: Non-detailed answer: create a service, import the service, call the functions on the service from other components

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's just a set of one off helper functions the easiest way is create an @Injectable service with your helper methods then inject that into any component that requires them. You can provide public vars as well so they're accessible in your html.

```
@Injectable()
export class Helpers {
    helper1() { return "hello"; }
    helper2(x) { return x + 1 }
}

@Component({
    providers: [Helpers],
    template: "<div>{{helper1()}}</div>"     // will display 'hello'
)}
export class MyComponent {
    public helper1: Function = Helpers.helper1;

    constructor() {
        console.log(Helpers.helper2(5));    // will output '6'
    }
}
```

This works great for a simple set of random utility functions. If you need something more in depth please explain and we can provide alternate solutions.

Comment: That's great, it's what I really need to be sure. I did here in this way but a found a limitation. In my service I can't access a variable in my component and as I'm using modal-driven forms, in some functions I need to access the form. Is it possible to do without sending the form as a parameter?

Comment: Ahh as a service no, If it's all separate you can pass by parameter but you said you don't want to do that. If you need to interact with the component in a meaningful way you'll probably want to create a component class which consumes this service, and interact with the parent component via @input and output

Comment: Understood. I'll try to follow this way. Thanks very much indeed Joshua.